# AWS lambda function timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 2 microservices. Each microservice lambda function timeout is set to 15 minutes but I get a timeout in 5 minutes when I monitor the logs on logz.io, any idea why this is the case. I increased the limit from 5 minutes to 15 minutes but it looks like this has no effect. Please help!

Comment: is there any API gateway in between?

Comment: can you update question and give info where ur setting timeout and what is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that your function completes in 5 minutes .Try adding sleep(10*60*1000)  i.e 10 minutes in the code and check the total execution time.

Answer (score 0):

All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300 seconds. The default timeout is 3 seconds, but you can set the timeout to any value between 1 and 300 seconds.

seems like your function is not reading your set time out.

- https://lumigo.io/blog/aws-lambda-timeout-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

make the change in the serverless.yaml file by adding "timeout" as one of the parameter and set its value. With this every new deployment will keep this value as timeout value.